# WPF AreaSeries: How to change background opacity?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, charts

I'm using AreaSeries from the WPF Toolkit to implement something like stacked areas.
But this is not really possible with the WPF toolkit, so I will simply plot two series, whereas the one in the back is the sum of the front series and the "stacked" one.
Therefore the opacity of the series should be 100%. But although i set every possible opacity to 1.0, the series still is a little transparent.
So, does anyone know, where is the secret switch?

Here is a snippet, so you can see where I already set the opacity, without effect...

```
Dim col As System.Windows.Media.Color
col = System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#ff00ff00")
Dim brush As System.Windows.Media.Brush = New SolidColorBrush(col)
brush.Opacity = 1.0
series.Background = brush
series.Opacity = 1.0
series.Background.Opacity = 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <ch:Chart Margin="56,21,50,72" Title="MyChart" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Window, Mode=OneWay}"  Style="{StaticResource controlStyle}" >

                    <ch:AreaSeries Name="DefaultArea" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Key}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" Opacity="1" Title="111111" >
                        <ch:AreaSeries.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ch:AreaSeries">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ch:AreaSeries">
                                            <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                                                <Path Data="{TemplateBinding Geometry}" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="Pink" Style="{TemplateBinding PathStyle}" Opacity="1" />
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ch:AreaSeries.Style>
                    </ch:AreaSeries>

                    <ch:AreaSeries Name="PersonnelArea" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Key}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" Opacity="1" >
                        <ch:AreaSeries.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ch:AreaSeries">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ch:AreaSeries">
                                            <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                                                <Path Data="{TemplateBinding Geometry}" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="Yellow" Style="{TemplateBinding PathStyle}" Opacity="1" />
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ch:AreaSeries.Style>

                    </ch:AreaSeries>  
                </ch:Chart>
```